# Testfor block with custom name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making "magic blocks": if you are standing on a specific block you get a potion effect like speed, instant health, strength, etc. The only problem is while trying to make it survival friendly I want the player to have to rename a diamond block to the certain name to make the potion effects work. `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:diamond_block 0 /effect @a minecraft:strength 5 30`

So that's what I use currently but is there an NBT tag that makes it so the detect part can testfor a diamond block that's been named in an anvil?

Comment: Once placed, the block loses its custom name

Comment: If you are okay with it, maybe use two command blocks with a hopper clock, then I can certainly help. That won't hurt, since you are making an adventure map. So mention me here, and I'll reply ASAP

Comment: Rajat Jain 4  I'm actually not making it in an adventure map just a concept but it could definitely be used in adventure maps. But what do you mean by 2 command blocks running off a hopper clock?

Answer (score 1):

When you place a named block, it loses its name tag, making it impossible to detect if it was ever named. What you can do, however, is set a custom data value:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ diamond_block 1
```

Then, replace `detect ~ ~-1 ~ diamond_block 0` with `diamond_block 1`. You can use values 1 through 15, but values above 15 are not supported.

Note: In some versions of the game (and possibly the latest updates), blocks with custom data may have a missing texture, and the custom data may not be saved properly. You'll have to look into this yourself as I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: I am aware that this is an option, but as I said I'm trying to make it survival friendly so is it possible to give a data value to a block in survival?

Comment: Nevermind I have an Idea, I can have fill clock doing /execute @e[type=Item,name=CUSTOM_NAME] /setblock ~ ~ ~ diamond_block 1 So that way I can have a custom named block and press q and throw it on the ground as an item and then it will do the /setblock with custom data value

Comment: As far as I know, custom metadata was broken with the introduction of block states.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks cannot have names.  If you use an anvil, that only renames the item stack.  Instead of trying to detect the block, try spawning an invisible marker armor stand with a custom name.
e.g. `/summon ArmorStand ~ ~-1 ~ {Invisible:1, Marker: 1, CustomName: "Magic Block"}`.  You could then use the execute command to do things based on that armor stand.

Comment: Since it is supposed to be survival friendly, you would still need to detect the use of a renamed item to summon the armor stand in the first place.